# Self-hosted WCF service maxing cpu load

Tags: multithreading, wcf, load, cpu, windbg

I am looking into an issue at work with a WindowsService that is taking 100% CPU on a machine with 16 CPU's.

The service is hosting a self-hosted .NET WCF service.

I have received a crash dump which I have loaded up in windbg, in order to look for clues.

So what I have tried:

- !threads :

  > ThreadCount:      646 
  >   UnstartedThread:  0 
  >   BackgroundThread: 643 
  >   PendingThread:    0 
  >   DeadThread:       2 
  >   Hosted Runtime:   no 
  >   
  >  642 of the threads were Threadpool workers as following:
  >     8   29 2a34 000000002068b510  3029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 0000000000563f50 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker)
- ~29s -> !CLRStack

  > 000000003c66eb70 00000000770512fa [GCFrame: 000000003c66eb70] 
  >   000000003c66ec40 00000000770512fa [GCFrame: 000000003c66ec40] 
  >   000000003c66ec78 00000000770512fa [HelperMethodFrame: 000000003c66ec78] 
  > System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object) 
  >   000000003c66ed70 000007fef7af1c9c System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
  >   000000003c66ede0 000007fef7a6c2f3 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
  >   000000003c66ee30 000007fef7a6c92a System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
  >   000000003c66f388 000007fef8d57d33 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 000000003c66f388]
- ~29s -> K

  > 00000000`3c66e858 000007fe`fd7010dc ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa
  >   00000000`3c66e860 000007fe`f8d049bf KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x79
  >   00000000`3c66e900 000007fe`f8d04977 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x16c
  >   00000000`3c66e940 000007fe`f8d048f8 clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x103
  >   00000000`3c66e9a0 000007fe`f8e9c5de clr!CLREventBase::WaitEx+0x70
  >   00000000`3c66ea30 000007fe`f8dc5a34 clr!WKS::GCHeap::WaitUntilGCComplete+0x2b
  >   00000000`3c66ea60 000007fe`f8d0c4f4 clr!Thread::RareDisablePreemptiveGC+0x176
  >   00000000`3c66eaf0 000007fe`f8dd1f3d clr!GCCoop::GCCoop+0x3d
  >   00000000`3c66eb20 000007fe`f8e898cf clr!AwareLock::Contention+0x137
  >   00000000`3c66ebe0 000007fe`f7af1c9c clr!JITutil_MonContention+0xaf
  >   00000000`3c66ed70 000007fe`f7a6c2f3 mscorlib_ni+0x521c9c
  >   00000000`3c66ede0 000007fe`f7a6c92a mscorlib_ni+0x49c2f3
  >   00000000`3c66ee30 000007fe`f8d57d33 mscorlib_ni+0x49c92a
  >   00000000`3c66eef0 000007fe`f8d556e6 clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
  >   00000000`3c66ef30 000007fe`f8d557af clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4a
  >   00000000`3c66ef70 000007fe`f8eda2c9 clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0x2e6
  >   00000000`3c66f120 000007fe`f8ee51b0 clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x2a
  >   00000000`3c66f200 000007fe`f8ee513e clr!DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame::DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame+0xa0
  >   00000000`3c66f240 000007fe`f8ee50b5 clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x38e
  >   00000000`3c66f340 000007fe`f8ee51eb clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x2bd
  >   00000000`3c66f3d0 000007fe`f8eda224 clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x23b
  >   00000000`3c66f430 000007fe`f8ee6baf clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0xb4
  >   00000000`3c66f5c0 000007fe`f8ee6ab3 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+0x4c
  >   00000000`3c66f5f0 000007fe`f8eda8a6 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0xf3
  >   00000000`3c66f6b0 00000000`76c9652d clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
  >   00000000`3c66f7f0 00000000`7702c541 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
  >   00000000`3c66f820 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

Im having a hard time interpreting the stacktraces since they dont hit any of my applicationcode.
Are they all just idle threadworkers, waiting for work?

Comment: What does `!runaway` report? If it shows a threads on top that are not a threadpool workers, it might give you the offender. Otherwise, look at why you have so many threads -- 646 is too many.

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer from SysInternals (Microsoft) and you can open the process details and see a list of threads and how much CPU the threads are taking. It can also load symbols and show you the entrypoint of the thread in question. Figure out which threads are using the CPU then debug those specific threads.

Comment: have you tried xperf/WPA?

Answer (score 1):

Threads with `WaitForSingleObject` are not critical, since they are waiting and not consuming CPU time. But be aware that your dump is only a snapshot and you might have had bad luck when taking the snapshot.

For a performance analysis with WinDbg you'd need several dumps during high CPU and compare them. If they all have similar stack traces, that's fine and you can conclude something. If they are all very different, it's almost useless.

The command `!runaway` seems more interesting here, since it lists CPU times consumed per thread, so you can identify the one(s) which are on high CPU. Again: having two snapshots that you can compare is helpful, because the main thread may still have consumed more CPU time in total than some short-living 100% threads.

If you can't use a performance profiler, [SysInternals Procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) can generate a series of dumps (`-n`) for you on high CPU (`-c`). Use `-s` to set the time between dumps. For .NET, don't forget `-ma` for full memory.

Other than that, 646 threads sounds a lot to me. The OS itself could be quite busy scheduling them.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the issue could be related to GC. Since this is a self-hosted service, it will use the Workstation GC by default, unless you enable the server GC manually:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx

Have you tried that and see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Is this really an answer? Sounds more like a comment.

Comment: It's an educated guess, based on seeing a fairly significant number of self-hosted WCF services suffering from the same issue, and the fact that the stack trace shown clearly indicates the thread is waiting for GC to complete (if you're allocating a lot of objects, then the workstation GC will impact you heavily on a 16-proc machine). I could certainly be wrong, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Sounds very plausible - I am switching to server gc, and are awaiting a deployment to see if it changes anything!

Answer (score 0):

Perfview from Microsoft may be helpful. From the link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/10/09/improving-your-app-s-performance-with-perfview.aspx

"Late last year, Vance Morrison, who is currently an architect on the .NET Framework Performance team, released PerfView, which is a new performance tool for .NET developers. PerfView helps you discover and investigate performance hotspots in .NET Framework apps, and enables you to deliver consistently high-performance apps to your customers.

Using PerfView, you can perform complex CPU performance analyses to solve hard-to-detect performance problems. PerfView's revolutionary grouping and folding features are what makes it possible to grasp and solve these difficult problems."

Answer (score 0):

use WPRUI.exe to capture a trace and analyze the CPU usage with WPA.exe.

[image]

Microsoft explained how to analyze the created trace in the following video:

**Defrag Tools: #42 - WPT - CPU Analysis** 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Answer (score -1):

Collect ETW with Perfview and follow the big % numbers.

try run in windbg ~*e!clstack => call stacks of all threads look for repeatable code.